# Triggering vue-select dropdown item selection in a unit test

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils, vue-select

**Problem**: can't trigger Vue-Select3 item dropdown selection programmatically in unit-tests.

I have tried with both `vue-test-utils` and `@testing-library/vue` as well as triggering a click event programmatically in a browser to force list item selection. However, none of these worked. The only way I managed to trigger selection is by getting a VueSelect instance and emitting 'input' event. I also tried to trigger different events on dropdown container, etc.

```js
// Failed

// testing-library
const dropdownItem = getAllByTestId('dropdown-item')
fireEvent.click(dropdownItem[0])

// test-utils
wrapper.find('[data-testid=dropdown-item]').trigger('click')

// In browser
document.querySelectorAll('.vs__dropdown-item')[0].click()

// Success
wrapper.find(VueSelect).vm.$emit('input', payload)
```

**Current result**: When a click event is triggered nothing happens.
**Expected result**: When a click event is triggered Vue-Select should select the item and emit 'input' event.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of selecting an option directly. You can use the `select` function of the `VueSelect` component, like that:

```
const wrapper = mount(YourComponent)
const vueSelect = wrapper.find(VueSelect)
vueSelect.vm.select(yourOptionToSelect)
```

That will work if you just want to select a specific option.

But yes, if you want to simulate the click on one of the options, that would not be helpful. And I know that this way of changing the state of a component is not the preferred way of doing this, but it is the only solution I've found.